# How to change display information on Zebra printer with ZPL?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I work with ZM400 printer and I need to replace either UPS firmware completely in the best case. If not - just remove that UPS icon on the printer screen.

[image: Icont to Remove]

Comment: have you already tried to flash the printer with the standard firmware?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does not have any effect. thx for your time

Comment: I'm not sure if that printer supports this, but the newest Zebra printers uses WML files to show the data on the display.On the printer memory are stored some WML files which correspond to the each screen you can see on the printer display.What you could do is to get an [allcv report](https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Using-the-SGD-Allcv-Command-U1-getvar-allcv-CR?language=en_US) and check if in the file list of the E drive you see a INDEX.WML file and delete it.The original INDEX.WML file stored on the Z drive will return to be the default index,which should be without the UPS logo